# Summarise number of specific rows containing string variables in R (dplyr/tidyverse codes are appreciated)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a big dataset with a variety of variables concerning infectious complications. There are columns, containing symptoms written as strings in the corresponding columns ("Dysuria", "Fever", etc.). I would like to know the number of positive symptoms in each observation. I have tried to write different codes, using `rowSums` within `mutate_at` with `is.character` and `!is.na`, trying to do it simpler and as short as a single line of code, but it did not work. 
example:

```
symps_na %>% 
  mutate_if(~any(is.character(.), rowSums)) %>% 
  View()
```

Then, I wrote a code for each column separately, trying to recode string variables to 1, convert them to numeric and then sum these ones to get the number of symptoms (see the codes below).

```
symps_na<-
  pb_table_ord %>%
  select(ID, dysuria:fever)%>% 
  mutate(dysuria=ifelse(dysuria=="Dysuria", 1, dysuria)) %>% 
  mutate(frequency=ifelse(frequency=="Frequency", 1, frequency)) %>% 
  mutate(urgency=ifelse(urgency=="Urgency", 1, urgency)) %>% 
  mutate(prostatepain=ifelse(prostatepain=="Prostate pain", 1, prostatepain)) %>% 
  mutate(rigor=ifelse(!is.na(rigor), 1, rigor)) %>% 
  mutate(loinpain=ifelse(!is.na(loinpain), 1, loinpain)) %>% 
  mutate(fever=ifelse(!is.na(fever), 1, fever)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(dysuria:fever), as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(symptoms.sum=rowSums(select(., dysuria:fever)))
```

but the column **symptoms.sum** returns NA's instead numbers.
Oh, sorry, just have realized that I have missed `na.rm=TRUE`! But anyway. Can anyone suggest a more elegant way how could one get the summary number of non-NA/string variables for each observation in a separate column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two sets of columns one where you need to check value same as column name and the other one where you need to check to for `NA` values. I have created a sample data shared at the end of the answer and the two vectors `cols1` which is a vector of column names which has same value as in it's column and `cols2` where we need to check for `NA` values. You can change that according to column names that you have.

```
library(dplyr)

cols1 <- c('b', 'c')
cols2 <- c('d')

purrr::imap_dfc(df %>% select(cols1), `==`) %>% mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% transmute_at(vars(cols2), ~+(!is.na(.)))) %>%
  mutate(symptoms.sum = rowSums(select(., b:d), na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
#      b     c     d symptoms.sum
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int>        <dbl>
#1     1     1     0            2
#2     0     1     1            2
#3     1     0     1            2
#4    NA    NA     1            1
#5     1    NA     0            1
```

**data**

Tested on this data which looks like this

```
df <- structure(list(a = 1:5, b = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("b", 
"c"), class = "factor"), c = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA), .Label = c("c", 
"d"), class = "factor"), d = c(NA, 1, 2, 4, NA)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df
#  a    b    c  d
#1 1    b    c NA
#2 2    c    c  1
#3 3    b    d  2
#4 4 <NA> <NA>  4
#5 5    b <NA> NA
```